# Where to download QGIS win7 x64 installer?

Tags: qgis

When I try to print big map (1200mm x 1200mm x 300dpi) on pretty strong computer (i7 975 12GB RAM) withj Windows 7 I obtain error Error - 'Image too big. Creation of image with bla bla pixels failed' - same on QGIS 1.7.4 and 1.8.0 versions.

Can anybody link x64 build of QGIS please - I'd like to check printing on that version? I don't wanna install programming tools and see same error after...

Comment: Export your map in vector format (SVG or PDF).

Comment: Of course I tried it before. 
PDF - only one, vector layer was converted into file or pdf crash at all, SVG - after conversion (with Inkscape - maybe you know better converter for this purpose?) looked terrible. Now I installed VirtualBox + Debian + QGIS, but still can't get even 500dpi (same error, but yes, 300dpi I can get, it's too low for me)...

Comment: I tried this task here and it worked (i7 8gb, win7, osgeo4w instalation). The result is a ~600mb image Are you using the osgeo4w instalation?

Comment: Yes, I am (on Windows; on Debian I'm using debian.gfoss.it - as written on qgis webpage installation). 
My project has 4 active layers: 3 raster (each 256col PNG, one 9856x11584, two 15400x18100 pix) and one vector (about 100-200 points). When I obtain about 600mb image it is OK (image is generated), problem appears when it's larger. Maybe reducing colors of result map may help, but I don't know how to do it. 
On Debian over virtual machine I obtained 490dpi (slowly!), on win7 ~200 (I can't install pure linux).
Thank you very much for your help and time you spent for answering :)

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there is no x64 version of QGIS because the dependencies are not available in x64 either.

Like so often everything comes down to man power.